# Logistic population: determine parameter $r$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The general forumla for a logistic population is:

$$ P_{n+1} = P_n + r*P_n*(1-\frac{P_n}{K}) $$

I was given $P_{12} = 95.75$ and $P_{14} = 98$, as well as $K = 100$.

To solve for $r$, I decided to set up two equations:

$$ 98 = P_{13} + r*P_{13}*(1-\frac{P_{13}}{100})

$$ P_{13} = 95.75 + r*95.75*(1-\frac{95.75}{100})

Solving via substitution becomes kind of messy; is there an easier way of solving for $r$?

If you believe solving r using the questions set up is not too difficult, what would be the most efficient way to proceed?

Comment: This Question could be improved by organizing the information better (present the recursive formula first and the known values last, then ask how to find $r$) and by using [MathJax formatting](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for equations.

Answer (score 0):

We have:
$$P_{n+1}=P_n+rP_n\left(1-\frac{P_n}k\right)\\P_{n+1}=P_n+rP_n-rP_n^2/k$$
Again for $P_{n+2}$
$$P_{n+2}=P_{n+1}+rP_{n+1}-rP_{n+1}^2/k\\P_{n+2}=(P_n+rP_n-rP_n^2/k)+r(P_n+rP_n-rP_n^2/k)-r(P_n+rP_n-rP_n^2/k)^2/k$$
You can see now this involves lot of calculation So it would be better do substitute the values

Comment: The answer for r is 0.325. The book gave the answer and I substituted it into the equation and it produced the right results.